# How can I add flavor to green tea at home?

Tags: flavor, tea

I often buy green tea with different flavors like lemon, strawberry, and jasmine from the market. I want to add these flavors at home.  Can you recommend how I might do this?

Comment: They might not be artificial.  I have a bottle of lemon oil / extract which is all natural.

Comment: Just be careful with essential oils - if they are not food safe, back off, if they are food safe, verify in what quantity they are food safe. Some citrus oils, if concentrated, can be used as turpentine (which they are chemically quite similar to).....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the flavour I suppose. For the most direct route, I would try just steeping the fruit/flavour in the tea/water for a bit (ie: sliced strawberry, sliced ginger, lemon zest/peel, etc...). I make a ginger/lemon "tea" with thin slices of lemon zest by just steeping it in water. No reason you couldn't add some green tea leaves to that as well. Lemon Juice, I add before serving.

As mentioned finding an extract could work as well. No idea about amounts, you'll have to do some research as to what is safe/appropriate. I haven't used them.

For a Jasmine Tea, I would probably just find a good tea purveyor and find a proper Jasmine Tea.

Answer (score 1):

Blending tea recipes yourself should potentially taste better than what you get in a pre-blended tea. If you buy a flavoured strawberry tea, there isn't much real strawberry. Instead, it's artificially flavored.

What you have to keep when adding fresh fruit to your tea, is to steep the tea without the fruit first, and add the fruit (juice) later. However, when you infuse fruits in dried form (jujube, goji berries), you can steep it together with the tea at the same time.

Besides fruits, also try to experiment blending different types of tea (green, black, oolong, pu erh etc..) with non-fruit herbs such as chrysanthemum, lily, and honeysuckle flower.

I've published a few recipes for which I'm not sure if it's appropriate to share the links here. Just message me for the details!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with blending yourself is that fresh fruits and flowers don't release flavor well in water.

The best would be to find dry ingredients such as fruits in dry form such as dried goji berries, jujube, mango.

For flowers, you can buy them fresh and dry them in direct sunlight or above the heater.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make green tea taste nice so that you get the benefits, add some squash or fruit juice depending on how sweet you like it.

Comment: By squash, I assume you meant the drink or syrup?  Its not common where I'm from, so at first I wondered if you'd meant the vegetable. Winter squash would make it sweet but very, um, specifically flavored  =)

Comment: Yes I did mean the drink - you would normally dilute it with water, I effectively dilute it with green tea.